# how to use symfony assert callback from within a form not linked to an entity

Tags: php, forms, symfony, assert

In my application I have a custom form not linked to an entity.

I want to make an assert callback like I'm used to do on regular entities.

Anyone knows how to do it ?
How can I add a violation in the following code since I do not retrieve the execution context ?

```
/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $form = $this;
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'constraints' => array(
            new Assert\Callback(function(Array $data) use($form){

            })
        )
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can have a class (Not entity) mapped to that form, and have the assert callback in that class like in this example:

http://blog.alterphp.com/2012/04/custom-form-validation-constraint-with.html

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working. the class has to be an entity with an identifier, but I don't want it to be one